# how to play a sound clip on web page on button click event

Tags: html

how to play a sound clip on web page on button click event.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  What kind of web app is it?  What kind of sound clip?

Comment: its an time base application.. so if user is on page and his any type of event starts at say 10 o'clock then he should be able to listen a sound clip which is in mp3 or in any compatible extension...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have now used  html tag which supports playing sound clips, keeping in mind that users system has sound card and sound driver and speaker installed properly.